# Programmatically Populate List with All Songs?

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, media-player, monodevelop

I'm aware of the `MPMediaPickerController`, but I am under the impression that it is only for a user to manually select songs?  I would like to populate a list with all of the songs in the library programmatically.  I am using C# in monotouch and would like to be able to do this in that IDE.  From this list, I would like to access the song metadata (such as artist and album information).

Is there an easy way to do this with monotouch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the [iPod Media library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to get a list of songs.  Offhand I'm not aware of any MonoTouch specific examples, but the Obj-C samples should be pretty easy to convert.

Comment: Yeah I did see that link...  I will see what I can do and await for other responses before I mark an answer.  Thanks, though!